# Cannot connect to Node Express server

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I created an Express server with express generator. When I run the server on my laptop's Ubuntu for Windows, it starts up fine. Now when I run `curl localhost:3000` in a separate terminal, I get the message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to host localhost port 3000: Connection refused`.

The strange thing is that when I take that exact same server and run it on my Desktop's Ubuntu for Windows, running the curl command above works fine.

Here is where it gets even stranger, when I run the server on git bash on my laptop, the curl command also works fine. Note, the curl command will work fine in either git bash or WSL if the server is running on git bash.

I have no clue why the server will not work properly on my laptop's Ubuntu for Windows. I thought WSL just uses Window's network, so why would running the server on git bash work properly, but not on WSL?

Googling this has not given me much help. I have uninstalled WSL and reinstalled. I have also tried running all the commands with sudo. None of that worked.